# Salvar Token na Maquina do usuario

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, microsoft-azure, oauth2

Fiz uma integração com o `GoogleDrive` e ao fazer toda a autorização na tela de consentimento, ele cria um `token` no `appdata` do usuário, porém eu coloquei esta aplicação no `Azure` em uma `VM`.

Só que ao criar este `token` ele esta criando no `appdata` da `VM`, mas eu gostaria que ele criasse na máquina do usuário que está acessando a aplicação, segue o código:

```
UserCredential Credencial = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets 
{ 
   ClientId = ClienteID, 
   ClientSecret = ClienteSenha 
}, 
scopes, NomeUsuario, CancellationToken.None, new FileDataStore("token.aut")).Result;
```

Se alguém puder me ajudar a resolver eu agradeço.

Comment: Você pode utilizar o storage do HTML5 para armazenar este dado, que tal?

Comment: esse token pode ser armazenado em cookie encriptado usando asp.net mvc ? ou usando LocalStorage ou Session Storage? ou usar em uma variável ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//Armazenando o token com localstorage
localStorage.setItem('nomedotoken', token);

//Obtendo token com localstorage
var token = localStorage.getItem("nomedotoken");

//Armazenando o token com sessionStorage
sessionStorage.setItem('chave', 'valor');

//Obtendo token com sessionStorage
var data = sessionStorage.getItem('chave');
```

sessionStorage permite acessar um objeto tipo session Storage. 
A sessionStorage é similar ao localStorage, a única diferença é que 
enquanto os dados armazenados no localStorage não expiram,
os dados no sessionstorage tem os seus dados limpos ao expirar 
a sessão da página

Usando Asp.net MVC armazenando em cookie encriptado

```
var client = new RestClient("http://localhost:15797");

var request = new RestRequest("api/security/token", Method.POST);
request.AddParameter("grant_type", "password");
request.AddParameter("username", Username);
request.AddParameter("password", Password);

 IRestResponse<TokenViewModel> response = client.Execute<TokenViewModel>(request);
 var token = response.Data.access_token;

 if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(token))
     FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(token, false);
```

Comment: Então tentei fazer isso no arquivo .cs mas não tem como, falta referencia

Comment: instala restsharp https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp

Comment: Então... mas como eu substituiria a parte... new FileDataStore("token.aut")).... exatamente? porque ali eu passo a pasta onde o token sera salvo... nesse caso ficaria como?

Comment: Nesse caso a cada requisição vai passar token no header  da requisição da uma olhada nesse video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=c4Fden4jptc&t=703s